# Cannot call method 'push' of undefined when appending JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web

Keep getting a error that I can't push a JSON object to a JSON array. Only changes I made was that I this function is in a different file and so I called it as a module.

**index.js**

```
var mods = require('../server/api/getUserMods.js');

var usernamePerms = [ 'settings', 'mod1', 'mod2' ]

console.log(mods.getUserMods(usernamePerms));
```

**getUserMods.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.getUserMods = function(input) {
  var umkModules = '../umk_modules/';
  var modules = '{"module":[]}';
  var moduleParse = JSON.parse(modules);
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    console.log("Parsing: " + input[i]);
    console.log("At: " + umkModules.concat(input[i],"/","module-view.json"));
    console.log();
    var readModule = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(umkModules.concat(input[i],"/","module-view.json"), 'utf8'));
    console.log(readModule);
    moduleParse['modules'].push(readModule);
  };
  modules = JSON.stringify(moduleParse);
  return modules;
};
```

The function `getUserMods` takes a array strings and searches within a specified file path finding a file called `module-view.json` then appending it to the empty JSON array.

When ran, I get this...

```
moduleParse['modules'].push(readModule);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
moduleParse['module'].push(readModule);
```

Your property is named `module`, not `modules`. And I'm not entirely sure why you'd use JSON when you can simply do:

```
var moduleParse = {
  module:[]
}
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yup, just spotted that.

Comment: Just spotted that you spotted!

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I thought it was something else because I had a prototype that was working fine. Thanks for the help.